# Is it possible to change only the picture?

Tags: html, css

I need help guys, how am I supposed to change the image together with the other image, like in queuing system, I'm using HTML. Please help, Thank You..

Here is the screen shot of my web page.

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: for example, when I click Next, the image will change and also the image of blood test..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#b49e1b998a030e3dc8084c2771498a38

You can do this a few ways either using an [if else statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) or a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
var changeIMG = document.querySelector(".changeIMG")
var oldSrc = 'http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02223/bear-cub-toy_2223075k.jpg'
var newSrc = 'http://image.mlive.com/home/mlive-media/width960/img/grandrapidspress/photo/2015/03/20/-6328b3da95a15820.JPG'

function changeSrc() {
  var imgElement = document.querySelector(".bears")
  var src = imgElement.src

  imgElement.src = src === oldSrc ? newSrc : oldSrc
}

changeIMG.onclick = function() {
  changeSrc()
}
changeSrc()
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.changeIMG {
  display: block;
}
.bears {
  display: block;
  width: 52%;
  margin: 1.1em auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn changeIMG btn-primary">
  Change Source
</button>

<img class="bears">
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea man, this help me a lot.